# Python's bz2 module not compiled by default

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction

It seems that Python 2.6.1 doesn't compile bz2 library by default from source.

I don't have lib-dynload/bz2.so

What's the quickest way to add it (without installing Python from scratch)?

OS is Linux 2.4.32-grsec+f6b+gr217+nfs+a32+fuse23+tg+++opt+c8+gr2b-v6.194 #1 SMP Tue Jun 6 15:52:09 PDT 2006 i686 GNU/Linux

IIRC I used only --prefix flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need libbz2.so (the general purpose libbz2 library) properly installed first, for Python to be able to build its own interface to it.  That would typically be from a package in your Linux distro likely to have "libbz2" and "dev" in the package name.

Comment: `bzip2` and `bzip2-devel` when using Yum on a distro like Centos.

Comment: The Debian package is called: libbz2-dev

Answer (score 30):

Use your vendor's package management to add the package that contains the development files for bz2.  It's usually a package called "libbz2-dev".  E.g. on Ubuntu

`sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`

Answer (score 20):

There are 2 solutions for this trouble:

### option 1. install bzip2-devel

On Debian and derivatives, you can install easily like this:

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2-devel
```

### option 2. build and install bzip2

In the README file of [bzip2 package](http://bzip.org), it is explained that under certain platforms, namely those which employ Linux-ELF binaries, you have to build an additional shared object file like shown below:

```
wget http://bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
tar xpzf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd bzip2-1.0.6
make
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
make install PREFIX=/path/to/local # /usr/local by default
```

The critical bit here is the following command:

```
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
```

I've done this and after that tried to build Python again, like shown below:

```
cd Python-2.7.3
./configure --prefix=/path/to/local 
make install
```

Comment: The readme says make -f Makefile-libbz2_so instead of make -f Makefile_libbz2_so

Comment: Unable to locate package bzip2-devel (squeeze)

Comment: @chovy: "apt-cache search bzip | fgrep dev". You can try "libbz2-dev"

Comment: Did the build Python succeed?

Comment: When I try compiling this way, I get an error that says "recompile with -fPIC". When I do `make -fPIC Makefile-libbz2_so`, I get `make: *** No rule to make target \`PIC'.  Stop.`

Comment: There is a bug here, if you have run `make`, it is necessary to run `make clean` before attempting `make -f Makefile-libbz2_so`.

Comment: @hlin117 `-fPIC` is a flag for the compiler, not an option for `make`. You have to pass it as an environment variable as follows: `make -f Makefile-libbz2_so CFLAGS="-fPIC"`

Answer (score 10):

If you happen to be trying to compile Python on RHEL5 the package is called **bzip2-devel**, and if you have RHN set up it can be installed with this command:

> yum install bzip2-devel

Once that is done, you don't need either of the --enable-bz2 or --with-bz2 options, but you might need --enable-shared.