# missing python bz2 module

Tags: python, linux, bzip2

I have installed at my home directory.

```
[spatel@~ dev1]$ /home/spatel/python-2.7.3/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

I am trying to run one script which required python 2.7.x version, and i am getting missing bz2 error

```
[spatel@~ dev1]$ ./import_logs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import_logs.py", line 13, in <module>
    import bz2
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

I have tried to install bz2 module but i got lots of error

```
 [spatel@dev1 python-bz2-1.1]$ /home/spatel/python-2.7.3/bin/python setup.py install
    ...
    ...
    ...
    bz2.c:1765: error: âBZ_FINISH_OKâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    bz2.c:1765: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
    bz2.c:1771: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âavail_outâ
    bz2.c:1778: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named ânext_outâ
    bz2.c:1778: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âtotal_out_hi32â
    bz2.c:1778: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âtotal_out_lo32â
    bz2.c:1778: error: invalid operands to binary +
    bz2.c:1778: warning: statement with no effect
    bz2.c:1779: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âavail_outâ
    bz2.c:1779: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named ânext_outâ
    bz2.c:1779: error: invalid operands to binary -
    bz2.c:1779: error: invalid operands to binary -
    bz2.c:1779: warning: statement with no effect
    bz2.c:1783: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âavail_outâ
    bz2.c:1784: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âtotal_out_hi32â
    bz2.c:1784: error: âPyMemberDefâ has no member named âtotal_out_lo32â
    bz2.c:1784: warning: passing argument 2 of â_PyString_Resizeâ makes integer from pointer without a cast
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Why not use pip to install your missing module?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Probably as you built python from source, you don't have bz2 headers.

Install them on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Fedora:

```
sudo yum install bzip2-devel
```

And build python again.
You may notice that python checks for lots of libraries when configuring/building, if you miss some of them you probably will get no support for libs like bz2 on your case.

You should get prebuild binaries to avoid this kind of stuff. Ubuntu 12.04 packs [python 2.7.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/python), the version your script needs.

Comment: Fedora package is bzip2-devel (at least as of Fedora 14)

Comment: I had to install all this to build a working python2.7 on CentOS6.4.

    yum install -y bzip2-devel zlib zlib-devel openssl openssl-devel

Comment: @Mithril After installing libbz2, we need to recompile python sitting in virtual env. Now, I'm not sure if after re-compilation, my already installed packages will remain as it.

Comment: This worked for me on python3 (3.6+). I use pyenv I just had to recreate the before after `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`

Comment: How to do this in RHEL?

Comment: Hey, I have this issue on rhel 7.. I have installed "yum install bzip2-devel" Still having this issue.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Same issue.  Though mine is _bz2

Comment: I have this issue on a Oacle Linux 7 VM where I don't have root access. Is it possible to force python to use a pip library instead of the OS one? ('pip3 install --user bz2file' alone didn't work)

Comment: @lv10 I'm also using pyenv but I don't get what are you saying (before after), may you explain in steps?

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 22

Comment: before execute yum install bzip2-devel, make sure /bin/python3 and /usr/bin/pip-3 link to the right version of your python and pip

Comment: Can confirm that running this and then a `make install` inside python3.8 dir resolved the issue!

Comment: Note that if you've compiled you're own Python distribution (eg through ```pyenv install```), you'll need to re-compile the distribution after installing the package.

Answer (score 64):

I had this happen for python 3.8.2 when importing pandas: `import pandas as pd`

resulted in a long error message ending with: "error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'"

This was resolved by doing the following 2 bash commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/
```

Then it worked fine.

Comment: that worked for me! I used Python 3.7, so I did this: `sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7`

Comment: Great answer, worked like a charm! No need for python rebuild, as suggested in other places.

Comment: I was in a virtual environment - had to do this as well: 
```sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  /workspaces/demo_classification/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/```

Comment: For pyenv user, need to copy this .so file to some paths like `~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/`.

Answer (score 15):

On CentOS 7, install bzip2-devel:

```
sudo yum install  bzip2-devel
```

Then re-compile python.

Comment: Applies to CentOS 6 as well

Answer (score 8):

If you python install on a specific location, just install `libbz2-dev` would not work.

There is a workaround for centos:

- Centos 6

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/bz2.so /python_install_path/lib/python2.7
  ```
- Centos 7

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.so /python_install_path/lib/python2.7
  ```

`python_install_path` usually is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`, you would need replace that if you have custom python path.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. I was unable to import bzip2 for a python script until I copied over this bz2.so file from the system installation over into my virtualenv folder.

Comment: I was using this solution until I read the other comment and installed bzip2-devel prior to building python 2.7.14.

Comment: I am in Python3, and get error: ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)

Comment: Worked for me in CentOS7 on a cluster where I don't have root access. How on earth did you work this out? Regardless of the method, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

the solution above can solve bz2 problems with python2.7. but not python 3.x
yeah, you need _bz2.cpython-3xm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, however you should build it in your own env.

here's my solution:

1. yum install bzip2-devel.  (or apt-get)
2. download bzip2-1.0.6. make && make install ()
3. build Python3's _bz2.cpython like this:

vim run.sh under python3's source code folder:Python-3.x.x

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64
make distclean
./configure --prefix=/home/xxx/Python3 && make && make install
```

you can set prefix the same of your pre version, that will not uninstrall any package you installed. And before that, make a backup folder.

Comment: could you please add the details between point 2 and 3? I'm using this script but still receiving an exception https://pastebin.com/DJxUXaYd "Could not import runpy module"

Answer (score 6):

In my case I got this error when importing pandas. Installing python 3.9.1 solved the problem.

My initial python version was 3.8.6. I was using PyEnv and running MacOS Big Sur.

Initially:

```sh
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Nov 21 2020, 02:39:42)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Installed python 3.9.1:

```sh
$ pyenv install --list
$ pyenv install 3.9.1
$ pyenv local 3.9.1
$ pyenv global 3.9.1
$ pip install pandas
```

Running again:

```sh
$  python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jul  5 2021, 22:26:09)
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it as below

1. `# sudo find / -name '*_bz2*'`

search result sample：

> /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

2. `# sudo cp /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/python3.8.5/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload`
3. `sudo mv _bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

if your python is **3.7**, you should change the file name from `36m` to `37m`.

Comment: thanks for this answer, due to this i solved lots of library problem , 
in server i have 3.6 in venv i have python 3.10 , so some modules are not available in venv python.

Answer (score 5):

It is happening because of a `.so` file being missing.

Say for `python3.7` download the file from:
[_bz2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so](https://github.com/azwyane/simple_text_editor/blob/master/edi/_bz2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

For different versions of `python` try finding this file for your version. Say for `python3.8` change `37` to `38` etc. and find and download the file.

Now for `Ubuntu`: copy the file inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.7` folder using `sudo` privilege.

To do this, go to the folder where the file is downloaded and execute the command (change your filename  and destination folder based on your `python` versions accordingly):

```
sudo cp _bz2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7
```

Finally download `python`, extract the zip file and after extraction configure and compile it:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

Answer (score 4):

You must reinstall `bzip2` by source code:

1. `yum install  bzip2-devel`
2. `wget http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz`
3. `tar -zxvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz`
4. `cd bzip2-1.0.6`
5. `make && make install`
6. configure and re compile python

those steps working sometimes.

Finally, I have figured out the problem, it needs the /usr/local/Python-3.5.2/**lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** , it must have a problem when I compile bzip2 by source code. I copy this file from another VM to solve the problem.

Comment: ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_bz2)

Comment: `stackoverflow.com/questions/13915137/how-do-you-assign-bz2-to-an-altinstall-of-python` save me

Comment: Can you post a new link? http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz does not work anymore...

Comment: New link: https://sourceware.org/pub/bzip2/bzip2-latest.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the development version of the bz2 c library installed.  You probably don't and that's why it wasn't installed when you built your user copy of python.  On Ubuntu it's the libbz2-dev package.  It's probably named the same or similar on Fedora.  Or you can download it from www.bzip.org.

Answer (score 2):

I should also add that on CentOS 6, make sure you have `bzip2-devel`, not `bzip2-libs` installed.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem when installing `Python` from a different location (I use `Python 3.7.5` on `Centos 7`).

Here are steps that I make it be able to work:

1. Export environment variables

```
export PATH=<YOUR_PYTHON_PATH>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PYTHONPATH=<YOUR_PYTHON_PATH>/lib/python3.7/site-packages
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64"
```

2. Install bzip2-devel

```
yum install -y bzip2-devel
```

3. Download & compile bzip2

```
wget/curl <bzip2_url>
make
make install
```

By doing this, you don't need to download the `_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file.

Answer (score 1):

It is only happening in Jupyter when importing pandas for me.

My fix was to copy the contents of `/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload` (including `_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`) to `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution on CentOS: (step 2-6 may skip)

1. `sudo yum install bzip2-devel`
2. download `bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz` from https://github.com/nemequ/bzip2/releases
3. `tar -zxvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz`
4. `cd bzip2-1.0.6`
5. `make && make install`
6. download file from https://github.com/Imaginashion/ccdev-vision/blob/master/.fr-d0BNfn/django-jquery-file-upload/venv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and move it to  `/[your python path]/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
7. `` sudo ln -s `find /usr/lib64/ -type f -name "libbz2.so.1*"` /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0 ``
   credit to https://michaelheap.com/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libbz2-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-on-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on debian stretch with a locally compiled python 3.6.9
In /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/, there was a _bz2.cpython-365m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so file (note the '**365m**' part...)
I created the symlinks to this lib, and it solved the problem :

```
sudo ln -s _bz2.cpython-365m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _bz2.cpython-369m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
sudo ln -s _bz2.cpython-365m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this annoying output and fixed that error. I got that error actually in `Python 3.7` and `3.8`. I didn't even have sudo privileges in my remote server but I managed to fix that error by downgrading Python. Installing `Python 3.6` instead of 3.7 or 3.8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu22.04 and poetry. In my case, the following commands worked:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
cp /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so <poetry-virtualenv-path>/lib/python3.11/site-package
```

You can check the poetry virtualenv path with the following:

```bash
$ poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.11.4  
Implementation: CPython  
Path:           /home/username/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/server-FhuNspaF-py3.11
Executable:     /home/username/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/server-FhuNspaF-py3.11/bin/python
Valid:          True
```