# Python import error no module named bz2

Tags: python, gensim

I have libbz2-dev installed however I am still getting the following  import error while importing gensim :

```
>>> import gensim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/krishna/gensimenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "/home/krishna/gensimenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/corpora/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .wikicorpus import WikiCorpus
  File "/home/krishna/gensimenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.py", line 21, in <module>
    import bz2
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

Comment: Did you checked following post? Was it helpful?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806325/4518277

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and the tip above didn't resolve it.
Perhaps before creating the virtual env you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

related:
[missing python bz2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do

```
pip install bz2file
```

Comment: i did try that did not work. I had to reinstall python recreate virtualenv and it got resolved. Still don't know what might have caused it.