# Can't use SPYDER (anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've installed anaconda for spyder ide. But I had multiple problems.

> runfile('C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py', wdir='C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py', wdir='C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects')
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py", line 13, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>
> File "C:\Users\Berk DOĞUŞ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 35, in 
>       "the C extensions first.".format(module))
>
> ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslib' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

I don't understand where I am making a mistake? I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089668/pandas-import-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslib) but it has led to a different issue:

> runfile('C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects') Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in runfile('C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder
>   Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py', wdir='C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder
>   Projects')
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'),
>   namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Berk DOĞUŞ/Spyder Projects/DogrusalRegresyon.py", line
>   12, in import pandas as pd
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 40, in
>   import pandas.core.config_init
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py", line
>   12, in import pandas.core.config as cf
>
> File "C:\AConda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py", line 57, in
>   import pandas.compat as compat
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'

Thanks for roganjosh. Just deleted the python.

[There is another error like :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybZi4.png)

Comment: There's a couple of points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089668/pandas-import-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslib) but I'm not sure it's conclusive.

Comment: Everything I can find seems to suggest just using `conda` to uninstall pandas and reinstalling it with `conda`. Did you already have a version of pandas installed?

Comment: I did where you conducted me at first comment. So the good news there is no error like above. The bad news is the new error has occurred :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deleted the python"? You mean you used `conda` to uninstall and reinstall pandas?

Comment: No I mean i did like "My guess is the virtual env is not using anaconda, and the install of pandas is messed up (perhaps created before installing anaconda?). I would delete this directory C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36 and see if that helps"

Comment: Ok, so the next step I would say is to try what I put in my last comment and hope that fixes it

Comment: How can i use conda command? Ive tried couple of times but didnt worked. Can i do it with pip command? // conda worked by the way //

Comment: You should also have `Anaconda Prompt` installed

Comment: If you used anaconda only for spyder, you might aswell just install python and spyder. First DL the desired python version (I recommand latest 3.x version), and then open a console and use `py -3.x -m pip install spyder`

Comment: And last point, the special characters in your account name might pose an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys thanks for everything. Found the solution. First of all if you have python and Anaconda at same the time, delete the folder of python. [Like Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089668/pandas-import-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslib)

Then listen roganjosh's advice and uninstal-reinstall pandas lib using `conda`. Then turn of and turn on spyder. That's all. Problem solved.

Comment: Hello IT, have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes but at last