# SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") in pip command

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-3.7, tls1.2

In my `Ubuntu 20.04`. I am using two `python` versions. One of them is `Python3.8.2` which came with my `Ubuntu` installation and another one is `Python3.7.5`. I installed `Python3.7.5` using `update-alternatives` alongside the system default version. But now the problem is no `pip` command is working on `Python3.7.5`. Although `pip` is available in this (`Python3.7.5`) installation and while printing the version it shows the following (using command `pip3.7 -V`):

```
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

But whenever I try to install a package using it always shows the error mentioned in the title. For example while installing the following package:

```
sudo pip3.7 install intel-tensorflow==1.15.2
```

The following error is thrown:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting intel-tensorflow==1.15.2
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/intel-tensorflow/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/intel-tensorflow/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/intel-tensorflow/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/intel-tensorflow/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/intel-tensorflow/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/intel-tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/intel-tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intel-tensorflow==1.15.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for intel-tensorflow==1.15.2
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Why this is actually happening? **Again it shows the same error for all pip3.7 installations no matter which module I am going to install**. Also there is no such problems like that whenever I am using the system default python version (`Python3.8.2`).

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333332/6849682?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TL;DR you're probably missing some system dependencies. `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`

Read below for the full details on how we got there.

The error states that the SSL python module is not available; meaning you either don't have an appropriate ssl lib installed (probably not since you state the system python can pip install fine), or the python you built from source or otherwise installed doesn't include the ssl module.

If you built it from source, you need to be sure to set the configuration option `--with-openssl`.

Also, I'd really caution against sudo pip installing anything. Use something like [virtualenv](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/) to have separate python environments from the system python or other python versions you install.

EDIT:

Upon closer examination, the python configure script appears to enable ssl support by default, assuming the dev headers are present. Make sure all the dev headers are present with `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`, then retry configuring and building python.

Comment: I installed python3.7.5 in the following way:
`sudo apt install build-essential`
 `mkdir ~/python-source-files` 
`wget -P ~/python-source-files https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz`
`tar xvzf Python-3.7.5.tgz` 
`cd Python-3.7.5`
`./configure --enable-optimizations` 
 `sudo make altinstall`

Comment: After that I also used `update-alternatives` to set a priority to them. Although I could not have done it as I am directly mentioning the pip version while executing the pip commands and before doing this I got the same error.

Comment: this looks to have changed a bit since I last did it. It could be that you just didn't have the ssl development headers present, so ssl support wasn't built. Let's make sure all your build packages are present; `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`. After that, try re-configuring python and look carefully at the output of config. You should see something about ssl being enabled.

Comment: No, still getting the same error after installing `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`

Comment: Did you then re-configure, and then rebuild your python? I've updated the answer to call that out a bit.

Comment: Rebuild?? Oh! Sorry, not actually.

Comment: The output of your `./configure --enable-optimizations` should call out including/excluding ssl support FYI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218556/discussion-between-kirk-and-hafiz031).

Comment: Yes after `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget` I executed `./configure --enable-optimizations` (going to Python3.7 directory) and executed `sudo make altinstall` and now it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, this one helped in my case before installing python from sources:
`sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`

With python 3.6 didn't have this problem at all, only happened when I tried to install 3.9

Comment: The correct answer seems to be installing the right dependencies, rather than enabling `--with-openssl`, which - as you point out - is enabled by default. This is a good answer, but it could be much more concise, and would be more clear if missing dependencies were mentioned first.

Comment: Install dependencies listed in the Python dev guide https://devguide.python.org/setup/#linux

Answer (score 3):

On Manjaro/Arch Linux I had to install `openssl-1.1`.

Running `import ssl` in a python repl revealed that libssl.so.1.1 was being read but not found.

Comment: Can you explain your answer ? What does it mean "being read but not found" ? How do you read something that you don't find ?

Comment: I meant to say that it was attempted to be read, but could not be found.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 this fixed it for me. I used the accepted answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 3):

For windows run following command before you run your actual command:

```
choco install wget openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 22.04**

`python -m pip install virtualenv`

That has revealed that I needed to add `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH`

`export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH`

After that
`pip install --user conan` or `pip install conan` should be successful.

Answer (score 0):

openssl is no more supported in centos7, To fix this issue, you must build python using openssl11 package instead of openssl, to do so:

- first install openssl11

  `sudo yum install -y epel`

  `sudo yum install -y openssl11-devel`
- build python:

  `cd Python-3.1X.X`

  `sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure`

  `./configure --enable-optimizations`

  `make altinstall`

Answer (score -1):

**If you've installed pyenv, uninstall it.**

```
rm -rf $(pyenv root)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

for windows,

delete the venv folder and recreate again.