# watchman: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, watchman

I'm on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-bit. I'm trying to install watchman as a part of a [React Native setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). I have followed the [official steps to downloading and installing watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html) for Linux and Mac, but I get the following error when I type `watchman` in the terminal:

> watchman: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

These are the installation steps for your reference:

```
$ unzip watchman-*-linux.zip
$ cd watchman-vYYYY.MM.DD.00-linux
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/{bin,lib} /usr/local/var/run/watchman
$ sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
$ sudo cp lib/* /usr/local/lib
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/watchman
$ sudo chmod 2777 /usr/local/var/run/watchman
```

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: @troy_achilies, no, I switched to expo...

Comment: Had the same problem, This solution worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633324/16173373