# ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, pipenv, cookiecutter-django, django-shop

When running a project via `pipenv`, I get the following stacktrace. As I typically do not work with `pipenv` and `cookiecutter` projects, I have been struggling to fix it. Any help is appreciated. In case it matters, it is [this project](https://github.com/awesto/django-shop) that I am trying to build and launch.

```
➜  project-shop git:(master) ✗ pipenv run ./manage.py runserver
    [2022-11-04 13:08:19,329 autoreload] INFO: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
    File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .documents import Document  # noqa
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 8, in <module>
        from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk, parallel_bulk
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        from .client import Elasticsearch
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from ..transport import Transport, TransportError
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 26, in <module>
        from .connection import Urllib3HttpConnection
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from .http_urllib3 import Urllib3HttpConnection, create_ssl_context
        File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-shop-d1PiLiCc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 18, in <module>
        import ssl
        File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
        import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
        ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/ubuntu-22-04-libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware Yes, I have tried following several solutions from that question. None worked.

Comment: Have you reinstalled your virtual environment?

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware How specifically should I do that?

Comment: I am not sure but `pipenv clean` could force remove the cached installation. Sorry I can't help more, I don't usually work with pipenv

Answer (score 0):

add :

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main

in /etc/apt/source.list

then ==> apt-get update ,

apt install libssl1.0.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).