# voxel51 / fiftyone: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, fiftyone

After installing and running [fiftyone](https://docs.voxel51.com/) in python (using ubuntu 22.04), you get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

[DISCLAIMER: credits for this answer should go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73604364/2496293)]

`libcrypto.so.1.1` is part of the `libssl` package, which is by default version `3.*` on ubuntu `22.04`.

You don't want to override your default `libssl` installation just for running fiftyOne. Instead, you can download an older version and install it in an isolated location. For example:

```
$ mkdir $HOME/Software/openssl_1.1 && cd $HOME/Software/openssl_1.1
$ cd $HOME/Software/openssl_1.1
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.1.1o
$ ./config && make && make test
```

Then before running your python program:

```
EXPORT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Software/openssl_1.1/openssl-1.1.1o
```

---

Why this  near duplicate answer?

1. The error message emitted when running fityOne is different from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72133316/2496293). So people looking for this specific error message may discard the existing question/answer as not relevant.
2. Also, the 'accepted answer' is not good practice. This attempts to
   rectify this situation.
3. People searching by the *fityOne* keyword will not land on the correct existing answer.

Comment: Consider `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Software/openssl_1.1/openssl-1.1.1o:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to keep the current items on the path instead of overwriting them.