# React Expo Go app not updating on Android when updating dependent component from StickerSmash Expo Tutorial

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Got to this step in the Expo Go tutorial where you start to make changes to Button.js:

https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/build-a-screen/#enhance-the-reusable-button-component

Despite making changes in the Button.js file and the Expo CLI saying "Android Bundling complete", the changes are not reflected in the StickerSmash app running in Expo Go on the Android phone.

**Environment:**

*Laptop*

- Node v21.2.0
- Windows 11 Pro (WSL2 Ubuntu)

*Phone*

- Expo Go (Android) 2.29.8

If I stop the app on the Expo Go CLI on my laptop and start it again, the updates are reflected.  However, that's painfully long.  Can't figure out why hot/dynamic reloading is not working.  Any suggestions of what to try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER:**

You have to install [Watchman](https://gist.github.com/Gabao-Farias/298b60040af36998b979dff939c1e616) in WSL2 Ubuntu for Expo

[Instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/) For Expo Installation;

> To use Expo, you need to have the following tools installed on your
> machine:
>
> Node.js LTS release - Only Node.js LTS releases (even-numbered) are
> recommended. As Node.js officially states, "Production applications
> should only use Active LTS or Maintenance LTS releases". You can
> install Node.js using a version management tool (such as nvm or volta
> or any other of your choice) to switch between different Node.js
> versions.
>
> Git for source control.
>
> > Watchman (for Linux or macOS users).

And when you successfully installed Watchman with instructions and check from terminal with "watchman --version";

You should move ( if it is not ) your Project Folder to root folder from mounted drive.

Example: If you see /mnt/c/windows as directory (/mnt/) it means you are in mounted drive. You should move it or create new expo app to the root folder using;

```
cd ~
npx create-expo-app
```

cd ~ command will move you to the root folder.

*TEST STEPS RESULTS; (Tested on WSL2 Ubuntu)*

1. Without Watchman. Result: Same as yours.
2. With Watchman and Project in root folder. Result: Fine.

**-- PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE UPDATE --**

It should reflect changes to the EXPO GO app when you saved the file after making changes. So, if it does not, you do not have to stop and start again. You can simply press 'R' to reload app. Reload is not the same with restart duration.

**

> Shake your phone to open Dev Menu and Enable Fast Refresh Mode.

**

Steps completed before answering;

1. npx create-expo-app StickerSmash
2. npx expo start
3. Made changes following docs on docs.expo.dev

--

- Windows 11 Pro (22H2)
- Node v21.2.0
- Expo Go Android v2.29.8

--

Final Codes;

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import ImageViewer from './components/ImageViewer';
import Button from './components/Button';

const PlaceholderImage = require('./assets/images/background-image.png');

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <ImageViewer placeholderImageSource={PlaceholderImage} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
        <Button label="Choose a photo" />
        <Button label="Use this photo" />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#25292e',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  footerContainer: {
    flex: 1 / 3,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 58,
  },
  image: {
    width: 320,
    height: 440,
    borderRadius: 18,
  }
});
```

Button.js

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function Button({ label }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={() => alert('You pressed a button.')}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonLabel}>{label}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonContainer: {
    width: 320,
    height: 68,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 3,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    paddingRight: 8,
  },
  buttonLabel: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

ImageViewer.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function ImageViewer({ placeholderImageSource }) {
  return (
    <Image source={placeholderImageSource} style={styles.image} />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 320,
    height: 440,
    borderRadius: 18,
  },
});
```

Comment: I followed the tutorial exactly.  It picks up changes made in App.js, but NOT Button.js.  It is set to Fast Reloading.  I even tried pressing R to reload the app; that does not work.  The only thing that works is stop/start.  It's like Expo is not detecting that changes were made in Button.js.  Almost as if the Button.js compilation is being cached someplace, and that cache is NOT being cleared for Button.js.  Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Are you having trouble with all the files expect App.js? For example if you make changes on ImageViewer.js, still same issue or not?

Comment: Exactly.  Changes are picked up in App.js, but not in any other files (eg. Button.js, ImageViewer.js, etc.).

Comment: @kvjava1 I've edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks.  Still working through the watchman installation, as nothing works straightforward, but making progress.  I'll let you know when watchman is working, and if it solves the original problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: @kvjava1 No problem at all. I hope you'll fix this situation.

Comment: Thanks @Melihcansahin,  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I've been a bit busy and haven't been able to validate that watchman solves the problem, but I think that's very likely to be the issue.  Given that, and that you've been extremely helpful in working towards a solution, I have awarded you the bounty.  I will reply here again once I've been able to fully validate the solution.  Thanks again very much for your help! :)

Comment: I just validated that it's working successfully now.  On the watchman homepage, I followed the "Prebuilt Binaries" installation instructions (https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install#prebuilt-binaries-1).  Then the only things that I had to do were 1) follow this solution for a watchman libssl.so dependency (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73604364/2082256), and 2) add .watchmanconfig file at the root of my project (with empty JSON content {}).  But it's working now!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! :)

Comment: Any time :) I'm happy to hear you fixed it.