# Downgrade OpenSSL 3.0.0 to OpenSSL 1.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

Ruby 3.0. demands version Opensl 1.1.1.

How to downgrade openssl 3.0 to openssl 1.1.1?

Tried install from source, got an error

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Here are some answers for Ubuntu. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading to Ruby 3.1 (or later) instead which comes with openssl 3 support out of the box.