# Failing tests on openssl,

Tags: linux, openssl

I am running command `make test` on a program to test openssl.

```
../test/recipes/70-test_verify_extra.t ............. ok   
../test/recipes/70-test_wpacket.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ca.t ....................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_cipherbytes.t .............. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_cipherlist.t ............... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ciphername.t ............... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_cms.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 5 (wstat 1280, 0x500)
Failed 5/6 subtests 
../test/recipes/80-test_cmsapi.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ct.t ....................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_dane.t ..................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_dtls.t ..................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_dtls_mtu.t ................. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_dtlsv1listen.t ............. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ocsp.t ..................... ok     
../test/recipes/80-test_pkcs12.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ssl_new.t .................. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/29 subtests 
../test/recipes/80-test_ssl_old.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_ssl_test_ctx.t ............. ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_sslcorrupt.t ............... ok   
../test/recipes/80-test_tsa.t ...................... ok     
../test/recipes/80-test_x509aux.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_asn1_time.t ................ ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_async.t .................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_bio_enc.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_bio_memleak.t .............. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_constant_time.t ............ ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_fatalerr.t ................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_gmdiff.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_gost.t ..................... skipped: No test GOST engine found
../test/recipes/90-test_ige.t ...................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_includes.t ................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_memleak.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_overhead.t ................. skipped: Only supported in no-shared builds
../test/recipes/90-test_secmem.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_shlibload.t ................ ok     
../test/recipes/90-test_srp.t ...................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_sslapi.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_sslbuffers.t ............... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_store.t .................... ok       
../test/recipes/90-test_sysdefault.t ............... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_threads.t .................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_time_offset.t .............. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_tls13ccs.t ................. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_tls13encryption.t .......... ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_tls13secrets.t ............. ok   
../test/recipes/90-test_v3name.t ................... ok   
../test/recipes/95-test_external_boringssl.t ....... skipped: No external tests in this configuration
../test/recipes/95-test_external_krb5.t ............ skipped: No external tests in this configuration
../test/recipes/95-test_external_pyca.t ............ skipped: No external tests in this configuration
../test/recipes/99-test_ecstress.t ................. ok   
../test/recipes/99-test_fuzz.t ..................... ok
```

here is the summary report,

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../test/recipes/80-test_cms.t                    (Wstat: 1280 (exited 5) Tests: 6 Failed: 5)
  Failed tests:  1-5
  Non-zero exit status: 5
../test/recipes/80-test_ssl_new.t                (Wstat: 256 (exited 1) Tests: 29 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  12
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=158, Tests=2641, 109 wallclock secs ( 2.00 usr  0.21 sys + 89.66 cusr 28.74 csys = 120.61 CPU)
Result: FAIL
make[1]: *** [Makefile:208: _tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/openssl-1.1.1o'
```

Indeed when I try to run the program I get the error like following: (I am running Kali Linux)

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to check some of  [this thread of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)  yet I mostly get 404 or error doesn't change.

Any fix ?