# No module named '_bz2' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, importerror, bzip2

When trying to execute the following command:

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

The following error occurs:

> from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor ImportError: No module
>   named '_bz2'

So, I was trying to install **bzip2** module in **Ubuntu** using :

> sudo pip3 install bzip2

But, the following statement pops up in the terminal:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bzip2 (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for bzip2

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Try `sudo pip3 -v install bzip2` for more verbose output.

Comment: The following error is shown:                                                                'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for bzip2

Comment: You won't be able to install bz2 with pip because it's not on pypi, it's part of the standard library. I wonder if you have the minimal python installed (which doesn't have all of the standard library). What is the output of `dpkg -l libpython3-stdlib`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module/61464947#61464947 this questions will resolve your problem

Answer (score 28):

---

If you compiling python yourself, you need to install libbz2 headers and .so files first, so that python will be compiled with bz2 support.

On ubuntu, `apt-get install libbz2-dev` then compile python.

Comment: Once install rebuild python3
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall

Comment: I am a newbie, how do you rebuild python?

Comment: @MAkin If you are asking how to rebuild python, then you have to figure out how the original python got in your system, then rerun the process with what I have answered.

Comment: if you are using `pyenv` remember to re-install the version of python with `pyenv install`

Comment: rebuild python3.10 works for me. thanks @ANILPATEL.

Answer (score 13):

I found a pattern in those issues.

It happens mostly if you are missing dev tools and other important libraries required to compile code and install python.

For me, most of those steps did not work. But I had to do the following :

- Remove my python installation

`pyenv uninstall python_version.`

- Then install all the build tools to make sure I am not missing any

`sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \ libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \ xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git`

- Reinstall the new python version

`pyenv install python_version.`

I hope that solves your issues.

Comment: This is the best working advice in case one has a virtual environment (pipenv in my case) located on some remote machine without big flexibility over there. Works with python 3.9.12

Answer (score 6):

In my case I got the error when importing Pandas. Installing Python 3.9 solved it.

My python version was 3.8.6. I am using Pyenv and running MacOS Big Sur.

Error

```sh
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Nov 21 2020, 02:39:42)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

installed 3.9.1

```sh
$ pyenv install --list
$ pyenv install 3.9.1
$ pyenv local 3.9.1
$ pyenv global 3.9.1
$ pip install pandas
```

Again

```sh
$  python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jul  5 2021, 22:26:09)
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

finally, I fix this problems in centos with python3.9,.when everything can't work,

1. we can download file:_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.

> downloads this file: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1iPuEBYnUABWf94QM9fQZgQ 提取码: nw2g

2. then renames file because i use python3.9, this file is python3.8 :

   `cp _bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  /usr/local/python3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/`
3. Modify file permissions if it's doesn‘t work

> chmod +x _bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

4. if it report `ImportError: libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` , we should make sure bzip is installed. use:
   `yum install -y bzip2*` .
   then execute `ln -s /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1  /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0` . execute `python3 -c 'import _bz2'`, it can working normally !!!

i search from  https://www.jianshu.com/p/b722adc2ba52.

Comment: tks @Reegan Miranda

Answer (score 1):

Using pyenv

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
python --version
pyenv install version
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experience the same error in a RHEL 7.9 with a own python version (compiled from the scratch)

```
[lsaavedr@boxer ~]$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Mar  7 2022, 12:20:27)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bz2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bz2.py", line 23, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
```

And I solved either copying or /symlink/ the bz2 shared library into the python3 directory tree:

```
[root@boxer python3.6]# pwd
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
[root@boxer python3.6]# ln -s ../../../lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[root@boxer python3.6]# rpm -qf ../../../lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
python3-libs-3.6.8-19.el7_9.x86_64
```

Then bz2 works fine:

```
[lsaavedr@boxer ~]$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Mar  7 2022, 12:20:27)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bz2
>>> data = b"""All in all, it's just another brick in the wall"""
>>> c = bz2.compress(data)
>>> c
b'BZh91AY&SY\xc5\xd1nL\x00\x00\x05\x95\x80@\x84 \x00:}\x9e\x80 \x001L&\x9a\x03LA\xa8\x06\x86\x86\xd4i\xbe\x96d\xed\xb6\x96\x17x\x82EB\xd0\x02\x90\xe3\x0b\x88\xaa\x92\xec\x8a\xef/\x8b\xb9"\x9c(Hb\xe8\xb7&\x00'
>>> d = bz2.decompress(c)
>>> d
b"All in all, it's just another brick in the wall"
```

Answer (score 0):

if sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev is not sense, you can
try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```