# ImportError: No module named '_bz2'

Tags: python, linux, pandas, redhat

I am trying to run Python3 application in linux server. Application breaks when it tries to use Pandas library. I have tried the solution in [No module named '_bz2' in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335503/no-module-named-bz2-in-python3) 
But it gives me **No package libbz2-dev available**. 
And also this solution [missing python bz2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)
Could you please help me with this.

Python environment is,

- OS Name - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
- Version - 7.7 (Maipo)
- Python - 3.5.6
- Pandas - 0.25.3
- python-dateutil==2.8.1
- pytz==2019.1
- six==1.14.0
- numpy==1.18.1

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [missing python bz2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently I solved the issue. I removed python from the system and installed it back. By using this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087184/installing-python-3-on-rhel

Answer (score 1):

Probably as you built python from source, you don't have bz2 headers.

Install them on Ubuntu/Debian:

> sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev

centos\Fedora:

> sudo yum install bzip2-devel

And build python again.