# Error during executing the python file with panda import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-venv

I have a simpe python file

```
import pandas as pd
```

Python vnev setup with following packages:-

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
numpy           1.18.1 
pandas          0.25.3 
pip             19.3.1 
python-dateutil 2.8.1  
pytz            2019.3 
setuptools      45.1.0 
six             1.14.0 
wheel           0.33.6
```

Python Version:-

> Python 3.8.1

OS:-

> Ubuntu 18

When I run the python program it throws following error:--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/data-structure/dict.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 70, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
  File "/home/blazehub/PythonProjects/python_venv/venv/py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 3, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Did something missing in setup I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [missing python bz2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)

Comment: Did you build python from source?

Comment: Nope no sucess with above solutions

Comment: Issue resolved..I had fallback to python 3.6 from 3.8