# Python3.7.4 - Error while importing pandas libraries

Tags: python, linux, pandas, import, bz2

I had installed Python manually by using below comamnd-

```
#cd Python-3.7.4
#./configure --enable-optimizations
#make altinstall
```

and later NumPy and Pandas libraries manually as below -

```
#python3.7 setup.py install
```

ERROR -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/core/api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py", line 104, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py", line 99, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats import format as fmt
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 75, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import stringify_path
  File "/opt/mycom/data/support/pandas-1.0.3/pandas/io/common.py", line 3, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Then I tried workaround around as mentioned below but it didn't help

[missing python bz2 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)

Below are OS details-

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
Linux NVMBD1CJH190V03 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Do you have bzip2 installed? Python won't be able to build optional modules that have missing dependencies. Did you try _recompiling_ the interpreter after following the steps in the linked question?