# Missing _bz when using fetch_openml // Missing _lzma when importing torchvision

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using Python 3.9.13. I installed scikit-learn from the terminal:
`pip install scikit-learn`

Then I tried to download the mnist dataset using `fetch_openml`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
raw_data = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
```

That gave me a long error message ending with:

```
fetch_openml with as_frame=True requires pandas.
```

However, I had `pandas` installed. So I looked more deeply inside the error message and I found that the exception causing that error was this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around and found a solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module).

I only had to add another step to that solution.
After installing `libbz2-dev` I only had `_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` on my computer which is used for python 3.8.x so it did not work with my version of python.
I changed the file's name to `_bz2.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and it worked after that.

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python3.9/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/_bz2.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `_lzma` library when I wanted to import `torchvision`.

The issue was solved with running below lines in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install liblzma-dev
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python3.9/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.9/_lzma.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```