# ImportError: No Module named bz2 for Python 2.7.3

Tags: android, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

I run this command:
`/usr/bin/python -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"`

and result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

also it is exist apt-cache search bz2

```
libbz2-dev - high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - development
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Importing ```bz2``` works just fine for me, however ```print bz2.doc``` doesn't. It would be useful if you provide the output of ```python -v -c "import bz2"```

Comment: python -v -c "import bz2" result is the same as /usr/bin/python -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8115329/256854