# Can't install opentok via pip due to "CompressionError: bz2 module is not available"

Tags: python, django, opentok

I'm running `ubuntu 14.04 64-bit`.
I created a virtual environment via pythonbrew venv using `python 2.7.5`.
I created a django application dependent to opentok python-sdk.
When I try to install opentok, it says:

```
CompressionError: bz2 module is not available.
```

It works fine using the built in python (/usr/bin/python)
But using the python provided py pythonbrew, I encounter the error.

This is not just another bz2 module error that can be solved by correcting paths as mentioned in a possible duplicate of this question. A pythonbrew virtualenv was used here meaning that this should use a different python other than the system python. The answer there suggests linking to the system python which is not very good. A virtual env is being used here to isolate the system python to the specific python I will use for my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

Answer (score 1):

First Install bz2 then try installing it again :

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

after give your pip command again  . Hopefully it will work

Comment: bz2 cannot be installed. It says Unable to locate package bz2. And I've already installed libbz2-dev it says it's already the newest version.