# My new virtualenv gets ImportError: No module named bz2 but system python can import

Tags: python, virtualenv

My virtualenv doesn't have the bz2 lib for whatever reason. I know I have bz2 becuase the system python can import it, how come my newly created virtualenv doesn't get it?

```
$ mkvirtualenv sentry
$ python -c "import bz2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bz2
$ deactivate
$ python -c "import bz2"
```

I also tried to recompile python into the virtualenv directory, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812781/pythons-bz2-module-not-compiled-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why my compilation failed is either that I was missing `bzip2-devel` or that I gave the wrong path to `./configure` when I did (not sure which of the two):

```
./configure --prefix=/home/deploy/.virtualenv/sentry
```

after which running

```
make
make install
```

worked fine

Answer (score 1):

If you can actually import bz2 try to explicitly create a new virtualenv with that particular Python:

```
virtualenv foo -p /path/to/system/python
```

You might want to do `which python` to check which Python you are using.

Comment: Doesn't virtualenv use/copy the system python by default when it's created?

Comment: I believe it uses whatever is in your PATH.