# How do you assign bz2 to an altinstall of python?

Tags: python, installation

I'm using redhat 5.8, which comes with python 2.4 installed automatically, but I'm using a python package that requires python 2.6 or higher.  SO, I installed python 2.7 alongside 2.4, so as to not step on the system version.

Now, I'm trying to install a package through pip, and get the following error:

```bsh
CompressionError: bz2 module is not available
```

I do, however, have the module on my machine, as evidenced when I do this the server version gives:

```bsh
[~]$ python -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"
The python bz2 module provides a comprehensive interface for
the bz2 compression library. It implements a complete file
interface, one shot (de)compression functions, and types for
sequential (de)compression.
```

and the 2.7 install errors in this way:

```bsh
[~]$ python2.7 -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named bz2
```

So, I have read these questions:
[Already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812781/pythons-bz2-module-not-compiled-by-default) and this [very good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2), but neither of these seem quite on the mark.  In the first case, the advice is to install the missing piece, and the second question is to remove (or stop referencing) the extra python install.

What I want to do is put in a symlink or some such so that the python 2.7 install knows where bz2 is so that I can use pip to install a python package.

Thanks,
B

---

**EDIT: more information**

So, after much research, it appears that the way the path variables are established changed dramatically in python 2.5  (probably why red hat hasn't updated).

So, in python 2.7 you can add to the PYTHONPATH variable by adding a file with the .pth extension in this folder:

```bsh
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I have tried 2 ways to get this to work properly.

First, I simply fed a number of the python 2.4 path files to 2.7.  This caused an error of a different type:

```bsh
[~]$ python2.7 -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload/bz2.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

So, that's something.

I also tried pointing the path to the libbz2.so file in /usr/lib/ which resulted in the familiar error:

```bsh
[~]$ python2.7 -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

I'm still stumped, but I feel like I'm closing in.

I could really use some input from someone with more experience setting up programming environments.  I'm much more comfortable just writing code :)

Comment: The first one is the correct fix. Your fix is not in fact any sort of fix, since it uses a completely different version of the Python library.

Comment: The first what is correct?  The first Answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just did this yesterday on the same platform and got it working. Here's what I did:

Set `CFLAGS="-I/path/to/bz2/include"` and `LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/bz2/lib"`. Make sure the bz2 library path is set in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You'll likely need to do a `make distclean` and `configure && make && make install`, though.

If that fails, directly edit the setup.py and make a replacement similar to the following:

```
# Gustavo Niemeyer's bz2 module.
if (self.compiler.find_library_file(['/home/someuser/packages/libbz2/lib'], 'bz2')): #lib_dirs, 'bz2')):
```

Note the commented out portion at the end of the second line is the original rest of the setup.py line.

Also, I found just downloading and building the latest version of bz2 and pointing all of the above to that easier than trying to get the system installed version to work.

Regardless, this definitely works. I did it yesterday :)

Comment: Hi jknupp  Thanks so much for trying to help.  Sadly, I don't know how to set the different FLAGS.  and what would I be remaking?  Pyton or bzip?

Comment: I found a tutorial that walks through this process: [here](http://andrew.io/weblog/2010/02/installing-python-2-6-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-dreamhost/)

Comment: Setting the flags depends on the shell you're using (they're environment variables, and different shells have different methods to set them). For example, in bash/zsh it would be "export CFLAGS="..." where the elided part is the value you want to set it to.

Comment: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to what? I can not understand yet

Comment: LDFLAGS and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the same. According to `stackoverflow.com/questions/23548188/how-do-i-compile-python-3-4-with-custom-openssl`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers provided are useful and helpful, but this is how I got this to work.

The problem wasn't that Python wasn't finding the files (as I thought), it just couldn't use them properly.  So, I vi'ed into the Makefile for bzip2, found the line that looked like this:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -Winline -O2 -g $(BIGFILES)
```

and added -fPIC to the line like so:

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -Winline -O2 -g $(BIGFILES)
```

and WHALA!  It compiled just fine.

Comment: I would like to concur that this is a necessary step as you can see from the `make` step of the Python installation process: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(compress.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're working with a python other than the system-installed one, I strongly suggest using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv. It sets up a "sandbox" for you with its own copy of python and redoes all the paths, etc. to point to the new copy. You can then use pip to install whatever packages you need.

Comment: That looks great, but how do I set up a different version of python using virtualenv?

Comment: Looks like I asked too soon, an explanation is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)