# 'bz2 is module not available' when installing Pandas with pip in python virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas, pip, bzip2, pythonbrew

I am going through this post [Numpy, Scipy, and Pandas - Oh My!](http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=416), installing some python packages, but got stuck at the line for installing Pandas:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas#egg=pandas
```

I changed 'wesm' to 'pydata' for the latest version, and the only other difference to the post is that I'm using pythonbrew.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915137/how-do-you-assign-bz2-to-an-altinstall-of-python), related to the error, but where is the Makefile for bz2 mentioned in the answer?  Is there another way to resolve this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to build python with BZIP2 support.

Install the following package **before building python**:

- Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS: `yum install bzip2-devel`
- Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`

Extract python tarball. Then

```
configure;
make;
make install
```

Install `pip` using the new python.

**Alternative:**

Install a binary python distribution using yum or apt, that was build with BZIP2 support.

See also: [ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

Comment: There is no other option? .. I have a python tarball and pip installed. I did pip install pandas and I am getting this error..

Comment: You need python with bzip2 libs linked in. That’s a build tome option. You either build your python interpreter from source, or install a binary python distribution which comes with bzip2 support.

Comment: just for further information. it seems setup.py decide whether compile bz2 
```# Gustavo Niemeyer's bz2 module.
if (self.compiler.find_library_file(lib_dirs, 'bz2')): xxxx```

Answer (score 20):

#### I spent a lot of time on the internet and got a partial answer everywhere. Here is what you need to do to make it work. Follow every step.

1. `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev` Thanks to **Freek Wiekmeijer** for this.
   Now you also need to build python with bz2. Previously installed python won't work. For that do following:
2. Download stable python version from https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ then extract that **Gzipped source tarball** file. You can use `wget https://python-tar-file-link.tgz` to download and `tar -xvzf python-tar-file.tgz` to extract it in current directory
3. Go inside extracted folder then run following commands one at a time

   - `./configure`
   - `make`
   - `make install`
4. This will build a python file with bz2 that you previously installed
5. Since this python doesn't have pip installed, idea was to create a virtual environment with above-built python then install pandas using previously installed pip
6. You will see `python` file in the same directory. Just create a virtual environment.

   - `./python -m env myenv` (create myenv in the same directory or outside it's your choice)
   - `source myenv/bin/activate` (activate virtual environment)
   - `pip install pandas` (install pandas in the current environment)
7. That's it. Now with this environment, you should be able to use pandas without error.

Comment: Also I recommend use `make altinstall` for not to replace default python version.

Comment: Also I'd suggest to use: `./configure --enable-optimizations` additionally to configure.

Comment: Thank you, I've searched many threads, this is the first "full" answer I've come across that worked for me. Thank you for the clear step by step

Comment: I had a problem where my pip was not able to recognize a tar.bz2 package. I had installed another version of python on ubuntu from source. 

Installing libbz2-dev fixed it. Eternally thankful to humans of stackoverflow. 

Answer (score 2):

### pyenv

I noticed that installing Python using source takes a long time (I am doing it on i7 :/ ); especially the `make` and `make test`...

A simpler and shorter solution was to install another version of Python (I did Python 3.7.8) using `pyenv`, install it using [these steps](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#installing-pyenv).

It not only saved the problem of using multiple Python instances on the same system but also maintain my virtual environments without `virtualenvwrapper` (which turned buggy on my newly setup ubuntu-20.04).

Comment: please summaries what "these steps" are. your answer does not explain in any way how or why this answer the question