# Issue while I import Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed `python 3.7` on a Google Cloud VM in the following way

```
 wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tgz
 tar -xf Python-3.7.4.tgz
 cd Python-3.7.4
 ./configure --enable-optimizations
 make -j 64
 sudo make altinstall
```

Then I have installed pandas

```
sudo python3.7 -m pip install pandas
```

but If I do

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/bz2.py in <module>
     17 from threading import RLock
     18 
---> 19 from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
     20 
     21 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346269/bz2-is-module-not-available-when-installing-pandas-with-pip-in-python-virtual), I do not know how to `Extract python tarball`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['bz2 is module not available' when installing Pandas with pip in python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346269/bz2-is-module-not-available-when-installing-pandas-with-pip-in-python-virtual)

Comment: @MayankPorwal how could you do that? How do you extract the python tarball? Unfortunately I do not understand.