# ubuntu - bz2 not available (/usr/bin/python older version, so am using /home/name/somedir for python

Tags: python, ubuntu

My server has python older version(2.6~), so I have created a separate dir for installing latest python. I have installed from binary .

Now, got error that 'bz2 module is not available'
got this problem when installing django-celery.

it is actually working from system level python like this:

/usr/bin/python:
python shell opens......
then, import bz2; works !!!

python (means, locally installed python, after source /venv/bin/activate)
in python shell, import bz2; says that it is not available.  Can you please make it work for my local version( not global one).

Resources I found and tried from :

[ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

[Python's bz2 module not compiled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812781/pythons-bz2-module-not-compiled-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support) describes the same problem but for zlib. In short, you'll need `libbz2.so` and its headers in some location where Python can find them. You might need to download the [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org) source code and compile/install that in your homedir as well.