# Missing BZ2 module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In `python3.6`, when executing the following command:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Reported Error:

```
from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

However, issue is that I don't have root access to machine to use the solutions posted on the same issue on [stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module)

On trying to locate `libbz2.so`, I received following:

```
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
```

To be noted: in my `bash_profile` the `LIBRARY_PATH` did not have '/usr/lib64' explicitly specified when I compiled `python3.6` from source.

Comment: Side-note: using virtual-environments you should be able to install those non-system libraries without any problem (assuming venv is available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bz2` is an optional dependency of python, but [`sklearn` assumes your python installation has this module](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7526).

There are at least two possible ways to fix this:

1. update your version of joblib to [make its dependence on `bz2` optional](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/pull/402/files).  ([Thanks to sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201147/missing-bz2-module-in-python/45201327#comment77370184_45201327) for pointing this out.)
2. or, [install `libbz2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/812781/190597) and then re-build python3.6.

Comment: From that issue in this link, it sounds like installing a new version of joblib (> 10/2016) might be enough.

Comment: @unutbu: I added some more info. Can you comment on it?

Comment: @SuJK I highly recommend going for approach 1 (update joblib) first. Foreseeing all the consequences of building python yourself (if it's one global install, you might destroy system-dependencies) seems hard. Also your non-root access should stand in the way.

Comment: @SuJK: If you do want bz2 enabled in python, I believe this is [the way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972897/190597) (for linux). Be sure to read the comment about `make clean` too.

Comment: @SuJK: You may also need to pass `./configure` an option to specify where to find libbz2. Run `./configure --help` to find the right option.

Comment: As a quick fix, I just tracked down all the files which imported `bz2` and removed the lines. It seems to work right now.  But I will recompile my Python.